# Using Overlay of StfalconImageViewer to close imageViewer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement StfalconImageViewer in my app using these links: [here](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/StfalconImageViewer) and [here](https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer). this is my code:

```
  View imageDetail = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_image_pager, container , false);

       ImageView back = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.back);
       TextView totalImages = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.totalImages);
       TextView imagePosition = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.mediaCounter);
       TextView sentDate = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.sentDate);
       TextView sentBy = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.sentBy);
       TextView sentTime = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.sentTime);

       back.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //what should I write here???
        });

 StfalconImageViewer.Builder<ChatMessageBuilder> builder = new StfalconImageViewer.Builder<>
        (activity,ChatImageData.imageMessages, (imageView, image) -> {
              Glide.with(fragment)
                   .load(image.getMediaAddress())
                   .into(imageView);
         });

//some other codes

 builder
     .withStartPosition(ChatMessageInterfaceFragment.imagePosition)
     .withHiddenStatusBar(false)
     .allowZooming(true)
     .allowSwipeToDismiss(true)
     .withImageChangeListener((position) -> {
           //some codes
      })
     .withBackgroundColorResource(R.color.background_light)
     .withTransitionFrom(messageImage)
     .withOverlayView(imageDetail)
     .show();
```

As you can see there is an Overlay named `imageDetail` and a button (in Overlay) named `back` which should **close** `imageViewer` and get me back to my RecyclerView but the problem is I can't really put a right code for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you know any proper ImageViewer with double tap to zoom, pinch to zoom and Slide to next and previous image, also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a long test and experiments finally found it. here is the code:

```
View imageDetail = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_image_pager, container , false);

       ImageView back = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.back);
       TextView totalImages = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.totalImages);
       TextView imagePosition = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.mediaCounter);
       TextView sentDate = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.sentDate);
       TextView sentBy = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.sentBy);
       TextView sentTime = imageDetail.findViewById(R.id.sentTime);

 StafalconImageViewer builder = new StfalconImageViewer.Builder<>
        (activity,ChatImageData.imageMessages, (imageView, image) -> {
              Glide.with(fragment)
                   .load(image.getMediaAddress())
                   .into(imageView);
         });

//some other codes

 builder
     .withStartPosition(ChatMessageInterfaceFragment.imagePosition)
     .withHiddenStatusBar(false)
     .allowZooming(true)
     .allowSwipeToDismiss(true)
     .withImageChangeListener((position) -> {
           //some codes
      })
     .withBackgroundColorResource(R.color.background_light)
     .withTransitionFrom(messageImage)
     .withOverlayView(imageDetail)
     .show();
```

now our onClickListener works:

```
back.setOnClickListener(v -> {
      builder.onDismiss();
});
```

If we use the base Class which mean **StafalconImageViewer** and not the
**StafalconImageViewer.Builder**, the **onDismiss()** method works fine!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use as `StfalconImageViewer viewer = builder.build();` followed by `viewer.close();` which also helps close the dialog.